# Indian passport holder with a self-transfer in Abu Dhabi

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, uae, self-transfer, auh

I'm an Indian passport holder. I have a round-trip flight booked from Baku to Bishkek, via a self transfer in Abu Dhabi. My layover outbound is 1 hour and 20 minutes; on the return, it is 6 hours and 30 minutes. Do I need to apply for a visa for this?

Comment: I think you do [UAE Transit visa](https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/visit-visas/transit-visa#:~:text=Transit%20visa%20is%20issued%20either,be%20extended%20to%2096%20hours.&text=Transit%20visas%20for%2048%20hours%20are%20issued%20free%20of%20charge,through%20a%20UAE%2Dbased%20airline) unless you are eligible for an exemption

Comment: So you have checked luggage? What are the airlines involved? 1h20 is extremely short for a self-transfer…

Comment: My guess is that you are travelling with Wizz Air. This means the check-in deadline in Abu Dhabi is 60 minutes before departure. If you have checked bags, that leaves you with 20 minutes to deplane, go through passport control, retrieve your bags, go through customs, go to departures, queue and drop your bags. This is not going to happen. Even if you don't have checked bags but need to go to the check-in desk (for documentation verification for instance, or to print your boarding pass, since mobile boarding is not available), the same timing applies. And if your incoming flight is late...